Unable to click scrolled element in WDIO , but it working via console not in browser.execute
In WDIO automation after scrolling in the page web page am able to new see elements are getting loaded. I can click those elements in console option E.g
Working in browser - document.querySelector('button[data-testid=Add]').click()
But if I use the same in the browser.execute it is not working after scrolling
code used in VS code await browser.execute("document.querySelector('button[data-testid=Add]').click()");
It should click in browser.execute block
